# get termset description sharepointOnline

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, term-set, taxonomyfieldvalue

how to get termset description using javascript. i get the term object but with not information about the description :

```
getTerm: function (termName,termId) {

    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);
    var termStore = taxSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();

    var termSets = termStore.getTermSetsByName(termName, 1033);  //Default Language

    var term = taxSession.getTerm(termId);
    ctx.load(termSets);
    ctx.load(term);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            console.log(term);
            console.log(String.format('Name: {0}', term.get_name()));
            console.log(termSets);
            //$('.tooltiptextF').innerText() = term;
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            console.log(args.get_message());
        });

}
```

Comment: it will be like `term.get_description()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the description, you need to use it as `term.get_description()`.

It is available as a method and not as property unfortunately.